# How change styles elements in android

Tags: android

I want to change the styles for elements of the application interface. I found such a resource: https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/febed84a3a3cb7c2cb80d580d79c31e22e9643a5/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes_base.xml

How do I know which set of parameters includes the following style:

```
<item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView.SpinnerItem</item>
```

And why are some styles do not work? This one I have such a problem?
I use AppCompat v7

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

[developers.janrain.com/how-to/mobile-apps/sdk/social-login/android/custom-ui-for-android/](http://developers.janrain.com/how-to/mobile-apps/sdk/social-login/android/custom-ui-for-android/)